# C# Excel-DNA debugging

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I am trying to build custom user defined functions with excel-dna. What is a possible way to debug the custom functions, I.e. set breakpoints, add watch windows etc? Is it possible to do it on visual studio?

Comment: "Easiest" is a subjective question, and hence not a good fit for this site. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project that uses excel dna from the solution explorer in visual studio. Then click properties, and then choose Debug. Now, choose Start external program and find the path of the Excel application. In the Start options, in Command line arguments, write the name of your excel dna addin.

[image]

After this, you just need to run your project in Debug mode.

Comment: Just a reminder that Excel-DNA v1.0.0 sets up the debugger automatically for you on every build, so you shouldn't have to do that manually... /cc @darkvalance

Comment: I exactly did this, but not working for me. I tried in 2 different machines, but nothing. There should be something else to set...

Comment: @johnnyontheweb, After building the project, excel dna creates two files "myaddin64.xll" and "myaddin.xll". Perhaps the excel app installed in your computer is 32bits, so you should use the xll without 64.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class that inherits from IExcelAddIn
in the AutoOpen() function I like to add some debug code to open my specific test workbooks.

```
 class MyAddin :IExcelAddIn
    {
       public void AutoOpen()
       {
          #if DEBUG 
           var xlApp =
 (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
          xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\dev\mytestworkbook.xlsb");
          #endif    
       }
    }
```